# Request a webservice behind a proxy on QT

Tags: c++, qt, web-services, proxy

Im trying to publish an application paper. My software is written in C++/QT and it usually calls some webservices by QNetworkRequest. One reviewer made the following comments:

> "Could not fetch alignments behind a proxy server. Add option to set a
>   proxy for connecting to internet."
>
> "When there is an institutional proxy, the application cannot connect
>   to internet. This is very common in many institutions. The application
>   should provide a way to set a proxy. I was unable to test the tasks
>   that require internet in Linux due to this problem."

I have no idea of what can I do to fix it, since I haven't access to any proxy server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a VM of any Linux and set up something like Squid proxy fairly easily.  I do this at work so that I can authenticate with the corporate proxy via my Squid instance. This lets me route non-domain Windows and Linux VMs through it for updates.

Squid may emulate several of the proxy types supported by [QNetworkProxy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkproxy.html).  Then you give the user of your program the option of supplying proxy configuration information that you pass to [void QNetworkAccessManager::setProxy(const QNetworkProxy &proxy)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#setProxy), which will route the request through the proxy.

You could also code the proxy usage into the code and ask the user to try it out until it works

Comment: Thank you very much. I could setup and test the proxy setting in a VM